# What is the right way to implement this templated decorator pattern for this situation?

Tags: c++, templates, decorator

```
template <typename T> class FooBase {
     void push(T& t) = 0;
     T pop() = 0;
}

template<typename T> class FooDerived1: public FooBase<T> {
}

template<typename T> class FooDerived2: public FooBase<T> {
}
////////////////////////////////
template<typename T, typename Foo> class Bar: public Foo<pair<T, int>> {
       void push(T& t) {
           int value = get_val();
           foo_.push(make_pair(t, v));
       }
       
       pair<T, int> pop() {
           return foo_.pop();     
       }    
       
       Foo<pair<T, int>> foo_;
}
```

So basically we have different instances of class Foo, "FooDerived1", "FooDerived2" etc

We have a class Bar, which is a decorator, on top of class Foo, which should take in different any children of class Foo.

The problem is that, the decorator would initialize class FooBase's template with a modified typename. Basically change FooBase to FooBase<pair<T, int>>

Inside class Bar, I would use all of Foo's interface, and also a wrapper, around the base class function

What is the right way to do this? Because when I am trying to initialize class Bar, I am confused.

```
Bar<float, FooDerived1<float>> bar1;
Bar<float, FooDerived2<float>> bar2;
```

I am not sure how this would work and what is the right way to accomplish, what I am trying to do.

Thank you.

Comment: typo: `Foo` vs `FooBase`

Comment: I do not understand the question, is `Foo<T>` used for anything in `Bar`? Why is it part of the template? `T==float` seems to define `Bar` exactly, `Foo<T>` is not necessary for any of that. Just a warning, you cannot replace baseclass in some type.

Comment: @Quimby Please look at it now. Modified the question. I am trying to wrap class FooBase or it's children.

Comment: @Quimby Probably I don't need to derive Bar from Foo, but how to I modify the incoming Foo's template type inside Bar?

Answer (score 3):

First, `Bar` needs only a single template argument. `T` can be deduced from an instantiation `FooBase<T>` via a type trait, or by using a member alias.

Then you can use SFINAE to check if that argument inherits from `FooBase` (which adds a second argument again):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T> struct FooBase { using type = T; };

template <typename T> struct Foo1 : FooBase<T> {};
   

template <typename T,typename = void> struct Bar;
template <typename T> 
struct Bar< T, 
            std::enable_if_t<
                std::is_base_of_v<
                    FooBase<typename T::type>,T>> 
                > 
       : FooBase<std::pair<typename T::type,int>> {};

int main() {
    Bar< Foo1<int>> c;
}
```

Though, this would be much simpler if you drop some restrictions. If `Bar<T>` does not require `T` to inherit from `FooBase` and if the caller instantiates it via `Bar< sometype::type >` then no SFINAE is needed and `Bar` could be simply `template <typename T> struct Bar : FooBase<std::pair<T,int>> {};`. Also it is not clear what is the relevance of the derived class for `Bar`. In your code `Bar` merely uses `T` and `FooBase`. However, I hope the above will help.

Comment: I think they want `Foo<T>` to be any subclass of `FooBase`

Comment: @AlanBirtles oh right.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Please look at the question now. I modified it and added more details. Basically I want Bar to
modify the template type of FooBase and or of its children

Comment: @user3443615 the edit doesnt change the answer. I still don't understand what is the relevance of `FooDerived1` or `FooDerived2` in `Bar`. `Bar` gets a derived class passed but then does nothing with it. It merely inherits from `FooBase`. Do you want `Bar` to inherit from `FooDerived1` / `FooDerived2` ?

Comment: @user3443615 perhaps `Foo` vs `FooBase` isnt a typo but you want something that isnt quite clear.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  Probably I shouldn't derive from anything at all. I just own an object of Foo(any child of FooBase) type that is being passed. I want to use it inside class Bar as I have shown.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Convert any child of FooBase<T> to the corresponding FooBase<pair<T,int>> and use that object inside Bar

Comment: @user3443615 what exactly do you mean with "Convert any child of FooBase<T>". Do you want `Bar< FooDerived1<T> >` to inherit from `FooDerived< std::pair<T,int> >`? I am starting to believe that is what you want.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I want Bar<FooDerived1<T>> to function as a wrapper around FooDerived1<pair<T, int>>. I am starting to think I should do away with the inheritance part in class Bar and simply use FooDerived1<pair<T, int>> as a member variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246401/discussion-between-user3443615-and-463035818-is-not-a-number).